# Dependencies issue building a Dockerfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2

I have been trying to build a Dockerfile from github but when i build it i got the following errors:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: subprocess32, sqlalchemy, scandir
  Building wheel for subprocess32 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for subprocess32 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for subprocess32: filename=subprocess32-3.5.4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl size=47608 sha256=fe35748bdc27c9d9c269fb1d612dd73cdfe617d4e2cd8cf80587d828df9bd297
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e3/c7/6a/434fc8f2936acc4964ded8478435a8ef7c69eb41df7007a49f
  Building wheel for sqlalchemy (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for sqlalchemy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-JdSdpB
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/
  Complete output (547 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy
  copying lib/sqlalchemy/inspection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  
  running build_ext
  building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cprocessors.so
  building 'sqlalchemy.cresultproxy' extension
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cresultproxy.so
  building 'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict' extension
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/immutabledict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/immutabledict.o -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
  i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/immutabledict.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cimmutabledict.so
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/sqlalchemy
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/sqlalchemy/engine
  copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/sqlalchemy/engine
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .

  running install_egg_info
  error: 'egg_base' must be a directory name (got `lib`)
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sqlalchemy
  Running setup.py clean for sqlalchemy
  Building wheel for scandir (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for scandir (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for scandir: filename=scandir-1.10.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl size=40684 sha256=0ebd2cf5afe24d5a60d5cd5a6f62ead402fc8c29c3dd71abcdf1e4378ebc427c
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/58/2c/26/52406f7d1f19bcc47a6fbd1037a5f293492f5cf1d58c539edb
Successfully built subprocess32 scandir
Failed to build sqlalchemy
Installing collected packages: subprocess32, lockfile, scandir, pathlib2, contextlib2, zipp, configparser, importlib-metadata, sqlalchemy
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: started
    Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ZJroJ3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/sqlalchemy
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/
    Complete output (841 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy
    copying lib/sqlalchemy/inspection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy
    .
    .
    .
    .
    running build_ext
    building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cprocessors.so
    building 'sqlalchemy.cresultproxy' extension
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cresultproxy.so
    building 'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict' extension
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/immutabledict.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/immutabledict.o -Wundef -Werror=implicit-function-declaration
    i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-2KjtLn/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/immutabledict.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/cimmutabledict.so
    running install_lib
    creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy
    creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine
    copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine
    .
    .
    .
    copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sqlalchemy/schema.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/interfaces.py to interfaces.pyc
    .
    .
    .

    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py to asyncpg.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 372
        async def _prepare_and_execute(self, operation, parameters):
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/aiomysql.py to aiomysql.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/aiomysql.py", line 102
        async def _execute_async(self, operation, parameters):
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py to _concurrency_py3k.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 46
        def await_only(awaitable: Coroutine) -> Any:
                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    

    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/plugin.py to plugin.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/plugin.py", line 46
        self, fullname: str
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/apply.py to apply.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/apply.py", line 41
        cls: ClassDef,
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/infer.py to infer.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/infer.py", line 39
        api: SemanticAnalyzerPluginInterface,
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/util.py to util.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/util.py", line 41
        is_mapped: bool,
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/decl_class.py to decl_class.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/decl_class.py", line 46
        cls: ClassDef,
           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/names.py to names.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mypy/names.py", line 31
        COLUMN: int = util.symbol("COLUMN")  # type: ignore
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/mutable.py to mutable.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/serializer.py to serializer.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py to hybrid.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py to engine.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/engine.py", line 98
        async def start(self, is_ctxmanager=False):
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/events.py to events.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/base.py to base.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/base.py", line 50
        async def start(self, is_ctxmanager=False):
            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/exc.py to exc.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py to session.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 83
        async def refresh(
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/result.py to result.pyc
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/result.py", line 18
        async def close(self):
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/indexable.py to indexable.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/instrumentation.py to instrumentation.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py to schema.pyc
    running install_egg_info
    error: 'egg_base' must be a directory name (got `lib`)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rx01B5/sqlalchemy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ZJroJ3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python2.7/sqlalchemy Check the logs for full command output.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install subprocess32 lockfile sqlalchemy -i https://pypi.python.org/simple' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

So i tried to install manually the following dependencies that are linked to a file on the github repository:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.0.14
zmq==0.0.0
pyzmq==15.2.0
psycopg2==2.6.1
lockfile==0.10.2
tabulate==0.7.5
pexpect==3.2
psutil==5.6.6
ipython==2.3.0
colorama==0.3.2
numpy==1.8.2
argparse==1.2.1
subprocess32==3.2.6
```

But running the command `$pip install psycopg2==2.6.1` i got:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-S6dRnw/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-S6dRnw/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-Mqd4AD
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-S6dRnw/psycopg2/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-Mqd4AD/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-Mqd4AD/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-Mqd4AD/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-Mqd4AD/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-Mqd4AD/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '12.7'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It seems the psycopg2 complains about inability to determine PostgreSQL version.
Looking at this https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/594

> The problem was fixed in #489 released in psycopg 2.7. We don't have plans to backport the fix to 2.6.
>
> Use a pg_config from a production version of Postgres not from 10 beta
> 4

I was wondering whether i can fix it or there is no way to do it.
Furthermore i installed the latest version of the psycopg package and built the docker again but i always get the same issue mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to use Python 2.7? If not I'd suggest using 3.X will solve a lot of issues with the libraries you're trying to use.

Comment: @daveydave They run the setup.py file using python2

Comment: @daveydave However i built their docker file downloaded from their github repository hence I expected all this to be right

Comment: Do you have a link to the dockerfile / github repository?

Comment: @daveydave Definitely, https://github.com/panda-re/lava/tree/master/docker

Comment: Sorry I had a go at building but it's taking a bit too long for me!

Comment: @daveydave no problem,the process takes some time. Anyway please let me know if everything goes well